# Triggering a Javascript callback after a completed ajax call within an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to trigger an action after a Javascript object has been created via an AJAX call. My object looks something like this:

```
function API(uid,accessToken){      
        $.ajax("path/to/file", {
            type: "POST",
            data: { user: uid, auth: accessToken },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(jsonData) {
                arrayname = jsonData[values]
            }
        });
}
```

I tried to use JQuery's $.when function to do a callback after the object setup is complete (ie. the array is populated with the ajax response), which looked like this:

```
        $.when( API = new API(uid, accessToken) ).then(function() {
                ...success function...
        });
```

...but the `$.when` function triggers with the arrayname values still undefined. From the function's standpoint the deferred object is resolved even though the object values have not yet been set. I've since tried a number of ways to make the API object become deferred based on the completing of the entire ajax call and the setting of the variables, but I'm a bit stuck on the best way to do this.

Any pointers would be most appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that error (unrelated to the issue at hand).

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the callback function when you create the object, like so:

```
function API(uid,accessToken, callback){      
        $.ajax("path/to/file", {
            type: "POST",
            data: { user: uid, auth: accessToken },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(jsonData) {
                arrayname = jsonData[values]
                callback(jsonData[values])
            }
        });
}
```

and then instantiate the object like so

```
var api = new API(uid, accessToken, function(array) {
    // success function
});
```

Comment: Thanks, and yes, I was doing this before and of course it works. However, I'm abstracting these data objects from the UI and need to be able to use them throughout the app--in other words, the callback function for the same object/method may vary by circumstance. That's why I was hoping to use JQuery's $.when function if possible.

Comment: Hm, I'm confused then. If the ajax call is where it is, won't it only run once, on initialization?

Comment: This one will, but other methods on this object (each of which might do an ajax call) can be run arbitrarily throughout the app. I want to separate the data objects from the views that use it. For instance, a method allows me to get the tags associated with a particular object, and they may be displayed differently at different times. Having the callbacks be established outside the functions that assemble the objects is consequently the goal.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is due to the "success" callback running after the "then" callbacks, you could try turning success callback into a then callback as well. I don't use JQuery but I guess it would look something like:

```
function API(uid,accessToken){      
    return $.ajax("path/to/file", {
        type: "POST",
        data: { user: uid, auth: accessToken },
        dataType: "json",
    }).then(function(jsondata){
        arrayname = jsondata[values]
    });
}

$.when( API = new API(uid, accessToken) ).then(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you use `$.when` is when you are correlating the callbacks of multiple promises, async tasks, etc. Since jQuery 1.5, all calls to `$.ajax` and all the wrappers (`$.get` and `$.post`) all return [promises](http://api.jquery.com/promise/). Therefore you don't need to wrap this call with the `$.when` statement unless you want to do `$.when(ajaxCall1, ajaxCall2)`.

Since you want to filter the result from the server, you should use the [pipe](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) method of promises:

```
function API(uid, accessToken)
  return $.post(
    type: 'POST'
    ,data: { user: uid, auth: accessToken }
    ,dataType: 'json'
  )
    .pipe(function(json) {
      return json[values];
    })
  ;
}
```

This allows you to write your code the way you desire:

```
API(uid, token)
  .then(
    // success state (same as promise.done)
    function(arrayname /* named from your sample script*/) {
      alert('success! ' + arrayname);
    }
    // error state (same as promise.fail)
    ,function(jqXHR, status, error) {
      console.warn('oh noes!', error);
    }
  )
  .done(function() { /* done #2 */ })
  .fail(function() { /* fail #2 */ })
;
```

Note: `promise.pipe()` also allows you to filter (change the data passed to) the error callback as well.